# Simple Harmonic Motion in Special Relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, harmonic-oscillator

I was trying to see what results I would get if I were to incorporate relativistic corrections into the case of a harmonic oscillator in one dimension. I thought that if the maximum velocity of the oscillating body were to approach relativistic velocities, the measurement of the time period of motion and related measurements should change. I assumed a lab frame $(t,x)$.

The equation of motion should be 
\begin{equation}\frac{dp}{dt}+kx=0
\end{equation}
where $t$ is the time measured in the lab frame. $\frac{dp}{dt}$ is calculated to be $\gamma^3m_0\ddot{x}$(since only $a_{\mid\mid}$ exists for this motion). Naively, I took this as my solution in the following way: 
\begin{equation}\gamma^3m_0\ddot{x}=-kx
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\implies\ddot{x}=-\frac{k}{\gamma^3m_0}x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\implies\ddot{x}=-\omega^2x
\end{equation}
So I took the angular frequency $\omega$ simply like that. However, I forgot that $\gamma$ is a function of $\dot{x}$ and this obviously complicates things... for instance the period becomes a function of velocity. I'm not sure if my approach is correct and I don't have the tools to solve the differential equation I would get if i were to open up $\gamma$, so my questions are the following:

1. Am I doing this right?
2. Am I missing something conceptually?
3. Is there a better way to approach the problem?
4. And if, by some miracle, my last expression for $\ddot{x}$ is correct, could I have
   some help solving the differential equation?

---

EDIT: If you are posting the relativistic expression, please post the corresponding evaluation of the Classical limit of your expression.

Comment: (4.) I don't think you can find an analytical solution for that. Also, How did you get $\gamma^3$? Can you post the calculation? Because I think you have missed something essential, when taking the derivative of $\mathbf{p}$ since the mass $m$ is not a constant.

Comment: @iharob You can find the derivation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_mechanics#Force

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get an exact solution for $t(p)$, although it involves a rather nasty integral that I'm not sure can be written in closed form.  Here's how:

The equations of motion are
$$
\frac{dp}{dt} = -kx \qquad \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{m} \frac{p}{\sqrt{1 + p^2/m^2 c^2}}.
$$
This second equation can be obtained by taking the equation $p = m v /\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}$ and solving for $v$.  Differentiating the first equation and plugging in the second then yields
$$
\ddot{p} = - \omega^2 \frac{p}{\sqrt{1 + p^2/m^2 c^2}}.
$$
where $\omega^2 = k/m$ as usual.
This is a second-order ODE of the form $\ddot{p} = f(p)$, and so can be solved (at least in principle) via the method of quadratures:
\begin{align}
\dot{p} \ddot{p} &= - \omega^2 \dot{p} \frac{p}{\sqrt{1 + p^2/m^2 c^2}} \\
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{1}{2} \dot{p}^2 \right) &= \frac{d}{dt} \left( - \omega^2 m^2 c^2 \sqrt{ 1 + p^2/m^2 c^2 }\right) \\
\frac{1}{2} \dot{p}^2 &= - \omega^2 m^2 c^2 \sqrt{ 1 + p^2/m^2 c^2 } + C,
\end{align}
where $C$ is a constant determined by the initial conditions.  In particular, if we take the case where the particle is released from rest a distance $A$ from the origin, then we have $p_0 = 0$ and $\dot{p}_0 = - kA$, implying that
$$
C = \frac{1}{2} k^2 A^2 + \omega^2 m^2 c^2;
$$
and so we have
$$
\frac{dp}{dt} = \pm \sqrt{ k^2 A^2 + 2 \omega^2 m^2 c^2 - 2 \omega^2 m^2 c^2 \sqrt{ 1 + p^2/m^2 c^2 } }.
$$

This is a separable equation, so in principle, then, we have an implicit solution for $t(p)$:
$$
t(p) = \int_0^p dp \left[ 2 C - 2 \omega^2 m^2 c^2 \sqrt{ 1 + p^2/m^2 c^2 } \right]^{-1/2}.
$$
Making everything as dimensionless as possible, we redefine $\tilde{p} = p/mc$ and $\tilde{C} = C/\omega^2 m^2 c^2$;  the integral then becomes
$$
t(\tilde{p}) = \frac{1}{\omega} \int_0^\tilde{p} d\tilde{p} \left[ 2 \tilde{C} -  2 \sqrt{ 1 + \tilde{p}^2 } \right]^{-1/2}.
$$
I don't know how to solve this integral, personally.  *Mathematica* tells me that there's a solution in terms of incomplete elliptic integrals, but it's not terribly illuminating;  and it seems pretty hopeless to try to invert this to get $p(t)$ and thereby get $x(t)$.

However, this expression can still be used to find the period of oscillation.  If we think about the oscillation, it will take one-quarter of the object's period to go from $p = 0$ to a maximum of $p$ (where $\dot{p} = 0$.)  This will be precisely where quantity in square brackets in the above integral vanishes.  In other words, the period $\tau$ will be given by
$$
\tau = \frac{4}{\omega} \int_0^{\sqrt{\tilde{C}^2 - 1}} d\tilde{p} \left[ 2 \tilde{C} -  2 \sqrt{ 1 + \tilde{p}^2 } \right]^{-1/2} 
$$
Note that the dependence on amplitude of the period is encoded in the constant $\tilde{C}$.  That said, I'm still not sure how to solve this integral, and *Mathematica* doesn't much care for it either.  If nothing else, it's amenable to numerical integration now.

**EDIT:**  In the Newtonian limit, we will have $\tilde{p} \ll 1$ at all times, and
$$
\tilde{C} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{k^2 A^2}{\omega^2 m^2 c^2} = 1 + \frac{\omega^2 A^2}{2 c^2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \sqrt{\tilde{C}^2 - 1} \approx \frac{\omega A}{c}.
$$
So the period in this limit becomes
\begin{align*}
\tau &\approx \frac{4}{\omega} \int_0^{\omega A/c} d\tilde{p} \left[ 2 + \frac{\omega^2 A^2}{c^2} - 2 - \tilde{p}^2 \right]^{-1/2} \\
&= \frac{4}{\omega} \int_0^{\omega A/c} d\tilde{p} \left[ \frac{\omega^2 A^2}{c^2} - \tilde{p}^2 \right]^{-1/2} \\
&= \frac{4}{\omega}  \left[ \arcsin \left( \frac{c \tilde{p}}{\omega A} \right) \right]_0^{\omega A/c} \\
&= \frac{4}{\omega} \left[\frac{\pi}{2} \right]= \frac{2\pi}{\omega}.
\end{align*}
So the Newtonian result for the period is recovered.  One could do a similar expansion to solve for $p(t)$ in this case, since we would get something like $\omega t = \arcsin (c \tilde{p}/\omega A).$

Comment: Thanks a lot! The approach seems legit, but I'm curious to know whether this boils down to the more familiar expression when we take the classical limit...

Comment: @PrishChakraborty:  I've added the Newtonian limit to my derivation above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! However, are you certain that a cleaner solution doesn't exist?

Comment: @PrishChakraborty: Nope!  There could well be a cleaner way to do this;  my method of solution could be just one of many ways to get at the result.  That said, I'm not optimistic that a closed-form solution for $x(t)$ and $p(t)$ actually exists, simply because closed-form solutions rarely exist for non-linear ODE systems.

Comment: I hoped for an expression that would perhaps make the relativistic effects a little more obvious, but maybe I'm just being blind, or greedy.

Answer (score 0):

> I was trying to see what results I would get if I were to incorporate relativistic corrections into the case of a harmonic oscillator in one dimension. [...]
>   $ \gamma^3~m_0~\ddot{x} = -k x $

Since your question is specificly about harmonic motion, we might (instead) insist on this solution

$$x[~t~] := x_{\text{max}}~\text{Sin}[~\omega~(t - t_0)~],$$

and ask about the expression, as a function of $x$, of a corresponding suitable conservative force (or eventually, the "shape" of a corresponding potential).

Consequently, we'd insert the "harmonic solution" into the left-hand side of your equation:

$$ \gamma^3~m_0~\ddot{x} \mapsto -m_0~\omega^2~x_{\text{max}}~\text{Sin}[~\omega~(t - t_0)~]~/~\sqrt{ 1 - \left(\frac{x_{\text{max}}~\omega~\text{Cos}[~\omega~(t - t_0)~]}{c}\right)^2 }$$

and ask how to express it as a function of the variable $x$ (instead of variable $t$). That's of course straightforward by inserting the harmonic solution:

$$
\begin{align*}
\gamma^3~m_0~\ddot{x} ~~~ & \mapsto -m_0~\omega^2~x~/~\sqrt{ 1 - \left(\frac{x_{\text{max}}~\omega~\text{Cos}[~\text{ArcSin}[~x/x_{\text{max}}~]~]}{c}\right)^2 } \\
~ & = -m_0~\omega^2~x~/~\sqrt{ 1 - \left(\frac{x_{\text{max}}~\omega~\sqrt{1 - (x/x_{\text{max}})^2}}{c}\right)^2 } \\
~ & = -m_0~\omega^2~x~/~\sqrt{ 1 - \left(\frac{x_{\text{max}}~\omega}{c}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x~\omega}{c}\right)^2 }.
\end{align*}
$$

Of course we should require $0 \lt x_{\text{max}}~\omega \lt c$, whereby the square root is always defined, and real.
In the ("non-relativistic") limit that $x_{\text{max}}~\omega \ll c$ (and since $0 \le |x| \le x_{\text{max}}$) this force expression approaches the right-hand side of your equation: $-m_0~\omega^2~x \equiv -k~x$.

It is also easily integrated to obtain the corresponding "relativistic harmonic potential form"

$$V[~x~] := m_0~c^2 ~\sqrt{ 1 - \left(\frac{x_{\text{max}}~\omega}{c}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x~\omega}{c}\right)^2 } - V_{\text{ref}};$$

where the term with explicit $x$ dependence in the limit $x_{\text{max}}~\omega \ll c$ approaches $m_0~c^2~\frac{1}{2}~\left(\frac{x~\omega}{c}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}~m_0~\omega^2~x^2 \equiv \frac{k}{2}~x^2$.

Comment: Prish Chakraborty: "_Thanks for your contribution._" -- You're welcome. "_Please read the edit!_" -- I did; and added some additional evaluations to my answer.